# close connection to radislabs memcached cloud

Tags: node.js, redis

I use node module [memjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memjs) with redis labs memcached cloud. Is there any way to close a connection? Thank you.

Comment: I can see in the library that a method is implemented to close all connections from client, are u looking for something specific ?

Comment: No, I am not looking for anything specific. Just close connections. What is the method to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [`github.com/alevy/memjs/blob/master/lib/memjs/memjs.js`](http://github.com/alevy/memjs/blob/master/lib/memjs/memjs.js)

There is a method which loops over the connected servers and close the connection for each one of them. another method is `quit` which actually makes use of `close`.

```
// Closes (abruptly) connections to all the servers.
Client.prototype.close = function() {
  for (var i in this.servers) {
    this.servers[i].close();
  }
}
```

As the documentation of RedisLabs shows, creating the client [here](https://redislabs.com/memcached-howto#opening-a-connection-to-memcached-using-memjs)

```
var memjs = require('memjs');

var mc = memjs.Client.create('hostname:port', {
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password'
});
```

will give you the option to do the following to close :

```
mc.close();
```